# Optaplanner VariableListener corruption

Tags: optaplanner

I'm facing a problem with Optaplanner.

It started when I was trying to implement a solution of type Pick and Delivery base on the VehicleRoutingProblem.
In one of my tests I see something wrong in the debug but the result seems to be the best solution.
This is what I see :

- Agent-0
- Customer-11_PICKUP_1_[1]
- Customer-12_DELIVERY_1_[]
- Customer-21_PICKUP_2_[2]
- Customer-22_DELIVERY_2_[]
- Customer-41_PICKUP_4_[4]
- Customer-42_DELIVERY_4_[]
- Customer-31_PICKUP_3_[4, 3]
- Customer-32_DELIVERY_3_[4]

This it the path of the linked list of customers.

The Agent-0 is the agent.

The Customer-XX is the customer.

PICKUP_X or DELIVERY_X is the type of thing the agent must do and the X represent the number of the item.

The thing in bracket is the content of the agent.

As you can see in the example, after the DELIVERY_4, the item numbered 4 appears but it is already delivered ...

I think there is a problem with the variablelistener.
There is a shadow variable (agentContents) in the Customer that tracks what the agent has.

So I decided to turn on the FULL_ASSERT.
And what I see is pretty interesting.
There is an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Solving failed.
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame$SolveWorker.done(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:298)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption: the entity (Customer-32)'s shadow variable (Customer.agentContents)'s corrupted value ([4]) changed to uncorrupted value ([]) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
Probably the VariableListener class for that shadow variable (Customer.agentContents) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed after completedAction (Undo(Customer-21 {Customer-12 -> Customer-32})).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:349)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertExpectedUndoMoveScore(AbstractPhaseScope.java:144)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.doMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:153)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:121)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:72)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:214)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness.solve(SolutionBusiness.java:307)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame$SolveWorker.doInBackground(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:287)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.swingui.SolverAndPersistenceFrame$SolveWorker.doInBackground(SolverAndPersistenceFrame.java:1)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The undo move seems to trigger the problem.
But I can't see where is the problem exactly. I think my variablelistener is offending.

Plus I don't undestand how to read this : Undo(Customer-21 {Customer-12 -> Customer-32})).

Have you some way to debug this ?
I can give you some code if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: That pattern is `Undo(entity {oldVariableValue -> newVariableValue})`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.
I managed to get ride of this exception by rewritting the variableListener.


The first version was maintaining the agentContents of the entity modified and then if there is another entity linked maintaining their agentContents. Like the variableListener in the vehicleRoutingProblem.


The second version maintains the agentContent of the whole entity chain by retreiving the agent and then loop through the whole chain and adjust the agentContents.
This is not the best way I think this is not efficient but it works.

Have you got a better way to do this ?